# use DLL in own DLL

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I am trying to write a plugin for IBA:

> 2.1 Create Plugin Project
>
> The plugin consists of a .NET dll. This dll can be created with Visual Studio .NET 2003 or Visual Studio .NET 2005 (ibaPDA- v6.8.0 itself is a .NET v1.1 application, not a .NET v2.0 application).
>
> Create a new project for a class library in your favorite language. Add a reference to the ibaPdaPluginInterface dll. This dll contains the definitions of the required interfaces and some required helper classes. You can find this dll in the bin directory of this package. This directory also contains an xml documentation file ibaPdaPluginInterface.xml that contains some extra information used by the intellisense of Visual Studio. This xml file is optional.

I am new to C/C++ and C#.

How do I add a DLL into a DLL? The plugin is a DLL that I have later to copy/paste into a special folder where the IBA server will pick it up and use.

I saw some references and examples about explicit linking, but my output is a DLL, not an EXE. I will not have a Lib function there to call LoadLibrary():

[Determine which linking method to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-160#determining-which-linking-method-to-use)

Comment: Regardless of what you are trying to do, if you want to use a function from a DLL, that DLL must be loaded. It does not matter if it is loaded from an EXE or a different DLL. If you want to use it, you must add, in your project settings, a reference to it. Or explicitly load it - harder to use.

Comment: A DLL uses another DLL in exactly the same way that an EXE uses a DLL

Comment: could add a code example? In General words it is clear. I need to add DLL into plugin I write that will be DLL too.